# How to make sorting work with a large vector size?

Tags: c++, sorting

I need to get the running time of several sorts.Here, for example, are 2 of them:

```
void bubble_sort() {
               
        auto start = getCurrentTime();

        for (int i = container.size(); i > 0; --i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; ++j) {
                if (container[j] > container[j + 1])
                    std::swap(container[j], container[j + 1]);
            }
        }

        auto end = getCurrentTime();
        time = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);
        //auto result = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);
        //std::cout << result.count();
       

        
    }

    void cocktail_sort() {

        auto starting = getCurrentTime();

        bool swapped{ true };
        int start = 0;
        int end = std::size(container) - 1;
        while (swapped) {
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
                if (container[i] > container[i + 1]) {
                    swapped = true;
                    std::swap(container[i], container[i + 1]);
                }
            --end;
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = end; i > start; --i)
                if (container[i] < container[i - 1]) {
                    swapped = true;
                    std::swap(container[i], container[i - 1]);
                }
            ++start;

        }
        auto ending = getCurrentTime();
        time = duration_cast<milliseconds>(ending - starting);
    }
```

Everything works when the array size is a couple of thousand and random values are also from 0 to several thousand.

But next I need to sort an array with a size of 200 000(buble sort) and random numbers in the same range.And then the program just works for a very long time, I waited a few minutes(I have a good processor and the result should be no more than 30 seconds) and finished, tried with another(cocktail sort) and the same result.I work in VS and I see that as if the processor is not working at full capacity, through the task manager, too, a couple of percent on VS.What can I do to make sorting work normally?

**algClass.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <set>
#include <queue>
#include <iterator>
#include "contain.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include "random_helper.h"



using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::duration;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;
using std::chrono::nanoseconds;


class allSorting {

private:    
    std::size_t size;
    std::vector<int> container;
    std::chrono::milliseconds time;

    



    /*
    template< typename T >
    void print_container(T&& container) {
        for (auto&& curr : container) {
            std::cout << curr << " ";
        }
        //std::copy(std::begin(container), std::end(container), std::ostream_iterator<typename T::value_type>(std::cout, " "));
    }
    */
    template<typename Iter >
    void Q_sort_help(Iter left, Iter right) {
        if (right - left <= 1) return;
        auto separator = *(left + (right - left) / 2);
        auto t_left = left, t_right = right - 1;
        while (t_left < t_right) {
            while (*t_left < separator) ++t_left;
            while (*t_right > separator) --t_right;
            if (t_left <= t_right) {
                std::swap(*t_left, *t_right);
                ++t_left;
                --t_right;
            }
            if (left < t_right) Q_sort_help(left, t_right + 1);
            if (t_left < right) Q_sort_help(t_left, right);
        }
    }


    


public:


    allSorting(std::size_t new_size) {
        size = new_size;
        container.resize(size);
    }

    allSorting() {
        size = 0;
        container.resize(size);
    }

    void fill_random_number(int left_b = 0, int right_b = 100) {
        fill_container(container, left_b, right_b);
    }
    

    void resize(int newSize) {
        container.resize(newSize);
    
    }

    int sizeOfVector() {
        return container.size();
    }

    void addValue(int value) {
        container.push_back(value);
    }


    void bubble_sort() {
               
        auto start = getCurrentTime();

        for (int i = container.size(); i > 0; --i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; ++j) {
                if (container[j] > container[j + 1])
                    std::swap(container[j], container[j + 1]);
            }
        }

        auto end = getCurrentTime();
        time = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);
        //auto result = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);
        //std::cout << result.count();
       

        
    }

    void cocktail_sort() {

        auto starting = getCurrentTime();

        bool swapped{ true };
        int start = 0;
        int end = std::size(container) - 1;
        while (swapped) {
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
                if (container[i] > container[i + 1]) {
                    swapped = true;
                    std::swap(container[i], container[i + 1]);
                }
            --end;
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = end; i > start; --i)
                if (container[i] < container[i - 1]) {
                    swapped = true;
                    std::swap(container[i], container[i - 1]);
                }
            ++start;

        }
        auto ending = getCurrentTime();
        time = duration_cast<milliseconds>(ending - starting);
    }

    void Q_sort() {
        auto starting = getCurrentTime();

        Q_sort_help(container.begin(), container.end());

        auto ending = getCurrentTime();
        time = duration_cast<milliseconds>(ending - starting);
    }

    void Counting_sort() {
        auto starting = getCurrentTime();

        auto max = *std::max_element(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
        auto min = *std::min_element(std::begin(container), std::end(container));
        auto new_size{ max - min + 1 };
        std::vector<int> t_v(new_size);
        for (auto& curr : container)
            ++t_v[curr - min];
        auto iter = std::begin(container);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < new_size; ++i) {
            std::size_t shift = t_v[i];
            if (shift != 0) {
                std::fill_n(iter, shift, i + min);
                std::advance(iter, shift);
            }
        }

        auto ending = getCurrentTime();
        time = duration_cast<milliseconds>(ending - starting);
    }


    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point getCurrentTime() {
        using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
        using std::chrono::duration_cast;
        using std::chrono::duration;
        using std::chrono::milliseconds;
        return high_resolution_clock::now();

    }

    long long getresultTime(std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start, std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end) {
        using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
        using std::chrono::duration_cast;
        using std::chrono::duration;
        using std::chrono::milliseconds;

        auto result = duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start);

            //return duration_cast<milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        return 0;
    }

    
    


    

    void print_container() {
        for (auto& curr : container) {
            std::cout << curr << " ";
        }
        //std::copy(std::begin(container), std::end(container), std::ostream_iterator<typename T::value_type>(std::cout, " "));
    }

   
    
    long long getLastSortingTime() {
        return time.count();
    }


    void printTime() {
        std::cout << "The time: " << time.count() << " ms\n";
    }


    void writeTofile() {
        std::ofstream file("result.txt") ;
        
        for (const auto& e : container) {
            file << e << "\n";
        }
    }

};
```

**Main**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <set>
#include <queue>
#include <iterator>
#include "contain.h"


#include "algClass.h"





int main()
{

    
    int menu{ -1 };
    allSorting testSorting = allSorting();

    constexpr std::string_view str_menu[]{
        


    };

    auto print_menu = [&]() constexpr {
        for (auto&& element : str_menu) {
            std::cout << element << std::endl;

        }
    };

    auto get_file_path = []() {
        std::string file_path;
        std::cout << "file name: ";
        std::cin >> file_path;
        return file_path;
    };

    auto enter_numb = [&](auto number) {
        std::cout << "input number:";
        std::cin >> number;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore((std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max)(), '\n');
            throw std::exception("error ");
        }
        else {
            return number;
        }
    };




    print_menu();

    while (menu) {
        std::cout << "choose state: "; std::cin >> menu;
        switch (menu)
        {

        case 1:
        {

            int size{};
            size = enter_numb(size);
            testSorting.resize(size);
        }

        break;
        case 2:
        {
            int rightBorder{}, leftBorder{};
            std::cout << "input left and right border" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> leftBorder >> rightBorder;
            testSorting.fill_random_number(leftBorder, rightBorder);
        }
        break;
        case 3:
        {

            testSorting.print_container();
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        break;
        case 4:
        {
            std::cout << "input sieze: ";
            int size{  };
            std::cin >> size;
            std::cout << "input sizeа: ";
            std::cout << std::endl;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                int number{  };
                std::cin >> number;
                testSorting.addValue(number);
            }

        }
        break;
        case 5:
        {
            testSorting.bubble_sort();

        }
        break;
        case 6:
        {
            testSorting.cocktail_sort();

        }
        break;

        case 7:
        {
            testSorting.Q_sort();

        }
        break;

        case 8:
        {
            testSorting.Counting_sort();

        }
        break;

        case 9:
        {
           auto time = testSorting.getLastSortingTime();
           std::cout << time << std::endl;

        }
        break;

        case 10:
        {
            testSorting.writeTofile();

        }
        break;

        case 0:
            break;

        default:
            std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
        }

    }


}
```

**random_helper.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

namespace detail {

    template<typename T, typename Always = void>
    struct uniform_distribution_impl {
        static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "T must be integral of floating point");
    };
    template <typename T>
    struct uniform_distribution_impl<
        T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>>>
    {
        using type = std::uniform_int_distribution<T>;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct uniform_distribution_impl<
        T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>>
    {
        using type = std::uniform_real_distribution<T>;
    };

}
template <typename T>
using uniform_distribution = typename detail::uniform_distribution_impl<T>::type;

template<typename t, typename cont_type = typename t::value_type>
void fill_container(t& container, int left_b = 0, int right_b = 100) {

    auto randomnumberbetween = [](int low, int high)
    {
        auto randomfunc = [distribution_ = uniform_distribution<cont_type>(low, high),
            random_engine_ = std::mt19937{ std::random_device{}() }]() mutable
        {
            return distribution_(random_engine_);
        };
        return randomfunc;
    };

    std::generate(std::begin(container), std::end(container), randomnumberbetween(left_b, right_b));



}
```

Comment: Can you provide a full [mcve] please?  Including all necessary headers, declarations, main function, etc, so that it can be compiled and run.

Comment: What's your basis for thinking bubble sort on 200000 elements should take only 30 seconds?  Thinking about O(N^2) that seems very optimistic to me.

Comment: @NateEldredge Maybe I'm wrong, but I don't think it should take more than 5 minutes like I had

Comment: Nate, it would require a constant of 0.75 nanoseconds. With 200,000 elements it likely won’t fit into your cache memory. Not a chance.

Comment: 5 minutes = 300 seconds instead of 30 means the constant would have to be 7.5 nanoseconds.

Comment: Just go and measure the standard library sort.

Comment: @gnasher729 I have someone else's table where sorting by insertion with 200,000 and random values was completed in 30 seconds, so I think it shouldn't take me more than a minute

Comment: @Alpharius *"I have someone else's table [...]"* -- this is a LOT more convincing than saying "I think". People think lots of things, often wrongly. Evidence is powerful. Next time, start with your evidence.

Comment: That is quite a bit of code to look through. Perhaps you could narrow the problem down for us? Where in the code does execution get hung up? You could try the occasional diagnostic message. For example, in `bubble_sort()`, I might add something like `if ( i % 1000 == 0 ) std::cerr << "Iteration " << i << ".\n"` to the outermost loop. (Note the use if the unbuffered `cerr` instead of the buffered `cout` -- just in case something would prevent the buffer from flushing.) Add something similar to the other sort, then see how much code you can eliminate while preserving the problem.

Comment: @JaMiT added that for 100,000 , he counts 1000 approximately once every 16 seconds.Maybe it really can't be fixed for the algorithm, although I have a quicksort for 100,000 executed in 0 milliseconds